# How to get JSON result of a mapped URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Suppose we have the following controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Index")
public class ControllerClass {

  @RequestMapping("/Result")
  @ResponseBody
  public List<Integer> result(){
     List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     result.add(1);
     result.add(2);
     return result;
  }
 }
```

Now I want to store the JSON result of the URL "/Index/Result" into a string. or simply, store the JSON result of controller after applying the annotations. note that it's not for testing and webservice matter considered for this purpose. any idea for that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where do you want to do this? What do you mean _after applying the annotations_?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject Jackson's [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) into the controller to manually serialize the result to `JSON` before returning via an [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html).

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

     @Bean
     public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
         // returning a plain ObjectMapper, 
         // you can change this to configure the ObjectMapper as requiered
         return new ObjectMapper();
     }
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Index")
 public class ControllerClass {

   @Autowired
   private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

   @RequestMapping(value="/Result", 
                   method=RequestMethod.GET, 
                   produces="application/json")
   @ResponseBody
   public ResponseEntity<String> result(){
     List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     result.add(1);
     result.add(2);
     String jsonResult = objectMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(result);
     // here you can store the json result before returning it;
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonResult, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

**Edit**:

You can also try defining an [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) that captures the response body for the request you are interested.

```
@Component
public class RestResponseInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

      public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
          // inspect response, etc...
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. but the problem is, I want to pass a URL to servlet and get the JSON result instead, without add anything to controller or any server side classes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put jackson dependencies in your pom.xml if they are not already there.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can also update your request mapping like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Result", produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
```

Comment: Everything works out fine, I can get the JSON result of the url in browser. but I want to store the controller result in java code, not in browser.

Comment: you want to print it to the log file? or you want it to persist to session? what you mean by "storing"

Comment: Gson gson=new Gson();

String jsonResponse=gson.toJson(result);

can give you the json String if this is what you want

Comment: let me be more clear. I want to pass the json result of the controller as the webservice output. there are four annotations above the method and each of them manipulate the result of the method in different ways.

Comment: Its a working restful webservice. You could have use restcontroller instead of controller which was the shorthand for controller + responsebody but the result would be the same